# Scheduler control create background

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, scheduler

I'm trying to create a UserControl under which I can show games scheduled to a specific place (and day). The place/day control is nothing more than a vertically oriented StackPanel divided into 5-minute-slots.

After each 15 minutes a Border is added to devide a quarter hour. See image:

[image]

What would be the best and most performant way to paint the background (the white and light gray elements and borders)? Currently in code-behind I bind to the loaded-event of the Control in which I add three Rectangels (white and light-gray) and a Border element.

Just to be clear. There could be many controls (50+) in a single view. This is the point where performance becomes a matter and I'm not sure if my way is the best or the one that suits best.

Any help or point where to start would be appreciated. Because of I'm currently starting the development of this it's ok to do it completely different than what it is now if needeed.

Edit: Applied changes as stated in the comments.

This is what I have so far:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="TheControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Height="12">
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Questions:

1. How can I get it managed, that after each third element a border should be added
2. How to set the color to white, white, gray, white, white, gray and so on via triggers?

Comment: 50 controls should not cause any performance problem. Before you start you should read about MVVM design pattern and not do this in code behind!

Comment: Agreed. WPF is not about code behind. It's about XAML and DataBinding. What you need here is an `ItemsControl` and a proper Data Model that you can put in an observablecollection

Comment: I'm already using MVVM. But how should the rendering be made in a ViewModel to make it more performant. @FlatEric: Currently it is causing performance issues when more than 50 elements.

Comment: Read up on control Virtualization. You don't need to actually draw each and every control in your windows. UI Virtualization only instantiates the controls that are on screen.

Comment: Also you should not ever use the "loaded-event" in MVVM.

Comment: Also your styling should be done using triggers.

Comment: Updated with the XAML I have so far